# Sorting 1 Million Integers Using Threads in Windows

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, sorting

I have a task which is Sorting 1 million random integers with `8` threads in C programming language (in Windows platform).

1. I have to create a binary file with 1 million random integer inside. (Done)
2. I have to buffer these integers into an array. (Done)
3. I have to create 8 threads. (Done) Each thread takes 1/8 of the array and sorts it (Algorithm could be Merge or Quick Sort).
4. Then merge all sub arrays to construct a completely sorted array.

[Here's a detailed description for threads.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLVhu.jpg)

I'm writing codes on Visual Studio 2017 and here's my progress:

```
// 1MRandomNumber.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//    
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "time.h"
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

#define MAX_THREADS 8

static int numbers[1000000];

DWORD WINAPI QuickSort(LPVOID lpParam);

//Creating a File with 1000000 random integers;
void create1MBinaryFile(){
    int i, x;
    FILE *fp = fopen("1MRandomNumbers.dat","wb");
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i<1000000; i++) {
        x = (rand() * rand()) % 1000001;
        fprintf(fp,"%d \n", x);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("File is created\n");
}

//Buffers integers to "numbers" Array;
void loadFiletoArray() {
    int i = 0;
    char buf[128];
    FILE *fp = fopen("1MRandomNumbers.dat", "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in opening file");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000 - 1; i++) {
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp);
        sscanf_s(buf, "%d", &numbers[i]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("Numbers loaded to an array\n");
}

//Creates 8 Threads
void threadCreate() {
    DWORD   dwThreadIdArray[MAX_THREADS];
    HANDLE  hThreadArray[MAX_THREADS];

    for (int i = 0; i<MAX_THREADS -1; i++)
    {
        hThreadArray[i] = CreateThread(
            NULL,          
            0,                    
            QuickSort,      
            NULL,         
            0,                     
            &dwThreadIdArray[i]);   
        printf("Thread %d created \n", dwThreadIdArray[i]);
    } 

    WaitForMultipleObjects(MAX_THREADS, hThreadArray, TRUE, INFINITE);

    for (int i = 0; i<MAX_THREADS; i++)
    {
        CloseHandle(hThreadArray[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argv, char *argc[])
{
    create1MBinaryFile();
    loadFiletoArray();
    threadCreate();

    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI QuickSort(LPVOID lpParam) {

    return 0;
}
```

So how can I create multi-threads in Windows platform. In our lecture we've learnt to do that in POSIX library but I want to learn how can I achieve it with windows threading.

Edit: I Created `8` threads. Is this a true approach or should I change it? Also how can I split array for each thread and quicksort them?

Comment: There is a Windows implementation for the pthreads library, ought to be helpful to not have to rewrite the code.  Google can find it for you.  If it *must* be Windows-specific as an exercise then Google knows that too, query "windows how to create a thread".

Comment: this is probably a good place to start, but it seems like you're placing an extra burden on yourself by using a new API rather than what you're familiar with from lecture: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6h8hye8.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant It's not Windows-specific but i just want to learn it in Windows. I did some research and i read some article on Microsoft. But i can't get the concept.Especially in this sample code: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esszf9hw.aspx)

Comment: Note that since each thread will managing 1/8 of the array, it's safe to not have a mutex for reading/writing in the array IMHO.

Comment: @Tom's thanks for the comment i noted it. But i also don't see a reason for using mutex.I can achieve it without using mutex.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks OK, except that it creates 7 threads (MAX_THREADS-1) then waits for 8 threads. Also the code should use lpParameter as a pointer to a structure that specifies the 1/8th of the array to be sorted by the thread, which could be a pair of pointers (start and end pointers), or indexes. The code should read in the entire file into the array before starting the threads.

To split the array into 8 parts, then each 1/8th size = array_size / 8, with the last 1/8th being larger than the others (by up to 7 larger). If you want a more even split, let `remainder` = array_size % 8. Then the first `remainder` threads get a size of (array_size / 8) + 1, and the rest get a size of (array_size / 8).

Optional - you could use the threads for the merging. Numbering the threads 0 to 7, then thread 6 could wait for thread 7 to exit, then merge parts 6 and 7. Thread 4 could wait for thread 5, merge parts 4 and 5, then wait for thread 6, and merge the merged 4,5 and 6,7, and so on. I'm not sure this would be much faster than a single threaded 8 way merge.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When you say code you mean "CreateThread" part?Where after 3rd "," which i write "NULL"? If so how i can pass double integer parameters (for indexes) to there if it takes LPVOID type?Should i write another method for splitting Array then in QuickSort method check with if else columns like; "if(hThreadArray[0])then sort first array"?

Comment: @xBaskerville - create an array of 8 structures, each with a pair of pointers (start, end) or each with a pointer to the array and a pair of indexes (start, end) or (start, last). Then lpParameter for each CreateThread call would point to one of the 8 structures.

Comment: So, I created an array of 8 structures with 2 integer pointers.Should each proccess take 1 of them automatically?Because when i write pointers[i] in createthread block it says "no suitable conversion function from "arrayPointers" to "LPVOID" exists". Sorry for newbie questions but i couldn't get it.

Comment: @xBaskerville - use `&pointers[i]` or `pointers+i` for lpParameter.